# What happens if infinite insertion is carried out in a link list?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, heap-memory

Will the heap becomes full or any looping occurs if link list is set for infinite insertion. This question is asked for learning purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Each node you add to the linked list has to be allocated from *somewhere*; typically it would be allocated from the heap.

Therefore if you keep allocating nodes indefinitely, eventually your computer will run out of RAM to allocate more nodes, at which point the next node-allocation will fail (on some OS's, this might cause your process to be killed to reclaim memory so that the rest of the system can continue functioning).

Comment: `this might cause your process to be killed` or technically it may cause any other process to be killed instead, but this process would be quite a likely victim unless there are even worse memory hogs.